# query from two tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've 2 tables:
**nameTable**

- userName
- userId
- classId

**marksTable**

- userId
- classId
- courseCode
- marks

i want to display **userId, userName, courseCode, marks** of all the students having **same classId**.

```
create proc mark__classId
@classId int
as
select marksTable.courseCode, marksTable.userId, marksTable.marks, nameTable.userName
from marksTable, nameTable
where
marksTable.classId = nameTable.classId
```

but this query gave very vague o/p.

Suppose "**name1**" with id **NAME1** with classId **10** follows courseCode 'C1, C2, C3' with respective marks '80,99,90'
now I want to display all this information when I give input as

```
exec mark__classId 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select should be more like this, you just need to use your incoming parameters. As well as you should be using a `JOIN` instead of a `CROSS JOIN` with a filter

```
SELECT marksTable.courseCode, marksTable.userId, marksTable.marks, nameTable.userName
FROM marksTable
JOIN nameTable
    ON marksTable.classId = nameTable.classId 
WHERE marksTable.classId = @classId
```

Comment: thanks Mr justin. I've another query: how to filter out those userId for which there is no entry in marksTABLE i.e their marks are not allocated still. when I run the above code, i got vague result due to those userId that do not have entries in marksTABLE.

Comment: @nischalinn Just add this to the end of your WHERE: AND marksTable.userId IS NOT NULL